# Wordpress plugin custom post type single page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a Wordpress plugin that creates a custom post type. That custom post type will need it's own single.php page. I know that I can just create a file called single-{custom post type}.php in my theme, but I need this file to be in the plugin directory itself. How do I get Wordpress to recognize that I want to use the single-posttype.php from my plugin directory instead of my theme directory?

Comment: I think that his might help you. Have a look. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96660/custom-post-type-plugin-where-do-i-put-the-template?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa#answer-96662

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what I use, just replace `dirname(__FILE__) .'/templates/` with whatever directory structure you have. The nice thing about this is it will default to the proper theme file if you don't have an "override" file at the `$file` location.

```
add_filter( 'single_template', 'override_single_template' );
function override_single_template( $single_template ){
    global $post;

    $file = dirname(__FILE__) .'/templates/single-'. $post->post_type .'.php';

    if( file_exists( $file ) ) $single_template = $file;

    return $single_template;
}
```

And of course your can do the same with with

```
archive_template
```

and

```
 $file = dirname(__FILE__) .'/templates/archive-'. $post->post_type .'.php';
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you sir!